# Go — declared and not used error, when I think I have done so to the variable

Tags: go

What's wrong with this code?

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.
func fibonacci() func() int {
    prev := 0
    curr := 1
    return func() int {
        temp := curr
        curr := curr + prev
        prev := temp
        return curr
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

*prog.go:13: prev declared and not used*

Comment: Instead of “what’s wrong with this code” you probably meant to ask (more specifically) “why does this code produce this compiler error”, right? Please be as specific as possible when asking questions in the future. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You declared a variable named `prev` and then never used it.

Specifically, you said `prev := temp`. This is creating a new local variable in the current scope named `prev`. I assume you meant to just say `prev = temp`, which modifies the `prev` variable inherited from the surrounding scope. Similarly you probably meant to say `curr = curr + prev` on the previous line, instead of using `:=`.

Comment: To elaborate, `=` assigns the right to the left, and `:=` creates a *new* variable named the left, and assigns it the value of the item on the right.

Comment: Thanks! Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

If you make the changes suggested by [Kevin Ballard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/582/kevin-ballard), then,

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.
func fibonacci() func() int {
    prev := 0
    curr := 1
    return func() int {
        temp := curr
        curr = curr + prev
        prev = temp
        return curr
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
```

The output is not the [Fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

For the [Fibonacci sequence](http://oeis.org/A000045),

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fibonacci() func() int {
    a, b := 0, 1
    return func() (f int) {
        f, a, b = a, b, a+b
        return
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

Comment: To add a tiny bit, you can also replace `curr = curr + prev` with just `curr += prev`. There's no functional difference, of course - just slightly fewer keystrokes.

Comment: Although you fixed the code and provided a program code suggestion for the seemingly wanted functionality of the program, you did not answer the actual question *what is wrong with the code*/“why does it produce that compiler error”. That’s why I will still down-vote it, even though it may be useful in a wider scope (which does not really fit this Q/A format).

Comment: I agree, and it was actually my intention to leave off the first two numbers of the sequence; I was just wanting to test closures.

Still, this may be helpful to some readers.