# Declared and not used - How to update a variable in IF Statement

Tags: if-statement, go, variable-assignment

I am trying to setup a bool variable with a default value and update it based on a condition, in Go Lang. The func **foo** compiles, But the function **bar** doesn't compile and gives an error "f declared and not used"

There is a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905708/go-declared-and-not-used-error-when-i-think-i-have-done-so-to-the-variable) - which doesn't explain the next question

**What is the correct pattern for this(bar function) in Go?**

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"strconv"
)

func foo(m map[string]string) bool {
    f := false

if _, exists := m["READWRITE"]; exists {
    fmt.Println("Before Updating f : ", f)
    f, _ = strconv.ParseBool(m["READWRITE"])
    //if err != nil {
    //  panic(err)
    //}
}

fmt.Println("After Updating f : ", f)

return f
}

func bar(m map[string]string) bool {
    f := false

    if _, exists := m["READWRITE"]; exists {
         fmt.Println("Before Updating f : ", f)
         f, err := strconv.ParseBool(m["READWRITE"]) // error on this line "f declared and not used"
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("After Updating f : ", f)

    return f
}

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{"READWRITE": "true"}

    fmt.Println(foo(m))
    fmt.Println(bar(m))
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go — declared and not used error, when I think I have done so to the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905708/go-declared-and-not-used-error-when-i-think-i-have-done-so-to-the-variable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> gives an error "f declared and not used"

`f` in your sample is a newly-declared variable. Its scope lies within the `if` block, and is different from the one originally declared at the start of your `main()`.

Here is a sample commented code that may help clarify (also available as a runnable Go Playground [snippet](https://play.golang.org/p/IebpOEkXMvl)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    food := "burger"                 // (1) variable 'food' is declared
    fmt.Println("food is", food)     // OUTPUT: "burger"

    if true {
        food := "fries"              // (2) a new 'food' variable is a declared here. it shadows the one in (1)
        fmt.Println("food is", food) // this accesses the 'food' var from (2). OUTPUT: "fries"
    }

    fmt.Println("food is", food)     // this accesses the variable from (1). OUTPUT: "burger"
}
```

Hope this helps clarify. Cheers,

Comment: Thanks makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

From [go-lang specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may
>   redeclare variables provided **they were originally declared earlier in
>   the same block** (or the parameter lists if the block is the function
>   body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables
>   is new

The `if` starts a new block and hence this line is declaring a new variable with name `f`.

On the other hand `=` operator is an assignment operator and hence the value from the previous scope is modified.

If you want to re-use the same variable, you can declare `err` explicitly.

```
 var err error 
 f, err = strconv.ParseBool(m["READWRITE"])
 if err != nil {
    panic(err)
 }
```

Comment: I found that. But, I really need to write code - where I change default values based on certain inputs (which happens to be include error getting returned - i.e bar function).. So I would appreciate any pattern help

Comment: @AdmiralThrawn edited with one way in which this can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

Context on why I am calling this out: For a person moving to Go from quite a few other languages, this would be an oddity.

I am adding this here - just to demonstrate that it might be useful to use a temp variable explicitly. barNotCorrectYet, has f being updated with the "default false" return from strconv.ParseBool (which would have changed the preset value). So, on cases where we want to ignore bad inputs, it will be useful to assign output to a temp variable, check if no errors were returned and then update the preset value **barCorrectHandlingOfTempVariable**.

```
func barNotCorrectYet(m map[string]string) bool {
f := true // preset value of variable

if _, exists := m["READWRITE"]; exists {
    var err error

    fmt.Println("Before Updating f : ", f)

    f, err = strconv.ParseBool(m["READWRITE"])
    if err != nil {
        // If error, wrong value got updated on f.. and erased preset value
    }   

}

fmt.Println("[Value could be wrong] After Updating f : ", f)

return f
}

func barCorrectHandlingOfTempVariable(m map[string]string) bool {
f := true // preset value of variable

if _, exists := m["READWRITE"]; exists {

    fmt.Println("Before Updating f : ", f)

    temp, err := strconv.ParseBool(m["READWRITE"])
    if err != nil { // Update only when there are no errors to not affect preset value
        f = temp
    }       
}

fmt.Println("After Updating f : ", f)

return f
}
```